# How to handle spaces in external process

Tags: powershell

I am trying to start a powershell process with spaces, see the below examples:

Working:

```
$path = "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe"
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "& $path"
```

Not working (with spaces):

```
$path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\CustomApp\Server.exe"
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "& $path; Read-Host"
```

Using `Read-Host` the error message is displayed before the console exits: The term 'x86' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

How can I handle the spaces with `Start-Process`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place your path also in single quotes:

```
$path = "'C:\Program Files (x86)\CustomApp\Server.exe'"
Start-Process -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "& $path; Read-Host"
```